# Nested array key value assertion in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, codeception

I am trying to assert that specific key of my nested array contains given value.
For example:
I have this:

```
$owners=[12,15];
```

Here is API response's key that I get from server:

```
$response=[
          'name'=>'Test',
          'type_id'=>2,
          'owners'=>[
                    [
                     'resource_id'=>132,
                     'name'=>'Jonathan'
                    ],
                    [
                     'resource_id'=>25,
                     'name'=>'Yosh'
                    ]
                   ]
          ];
```

I want to check that the at least one of my owner's array should have resource_id as 132. I feel there has been an assertion in PHPUnit assertArraySubset but it may have been deprecated.

Can anyone tell how I can match key with specific value in nested array?
I could not see any method in PHPUnit framework for that.

PS. Sorry for poor formatting of code, I don't know how to properly intend it here on SO.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's often a good idea to write own constraints to keep tests readable. Especially in cases like this when you have a nested structure. If you need it in just one test class you can make the constraint an anonymous class returned by a helper method with a meaningful name.

```
public function test()
{
    $response = $this->callYourApi();

    self::assertThat($response, $this->hasOwnerWithResourceId(132));
}

private function hasOwnerWithResourceId(int $resourceId): Constraint
{
    return new class($resourceId) extends Constraint {
        private $resourceId;

        public function __construct(int $resourceId)
        {
            parent::__construct();

            $this->resourceId = $resourceId;
        }

        protected function matches($other): bool
        {
            foreach ($other['owners'] as $owner) {
                if ($owner['resource_id'] === $this->resourceId) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        public function toString(): string
        {
            return sprintf('has owner with resource id "%s"', $this->resourceId);
        }
    };
}
```